# Intuition in choosing finite set of points in proof that Pointwise convergence implies convergence in pointwise topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, intuition, pointwise-convergence

I am trying to understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2208872/688539). I am trying to understand this answer. In both directions of proof, I am confused why we take a finite subset of the indexing set. Someone seems to have had the same doubt as me and repeated it in the comments, and they got the following reply.

> Because a basis for the product topology on $∏_{α∈A}X_α$
> consists of sets of the form $∏_{α∈A}U_α$
> , where $U_α⊆X_α$
> are open sets and only finitely many $U_α$
> s are not equal to the corresponding $X_α$
> . Considering only basic open sets of this form simplifies the problem

Ok, this makes total sense when we think of it in the product topology, but I am having difficulty thinking of what this means when considering the subset of that, which is done in pointwise convergence topology.

Comment: Think about projections: $f_n\overset{\to}\to f $ iff $\pi_{\alpha}(f_n) \to\pi_{\alpha}(f) $ for all $\alpha\in A$.